# 32bit compare and swap on a 64 bit word

Tags: c++, c, gcc, atomic, compare-and-swap

Say I have a 64 bit word (high32,low32) and  I do a `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` on a 32 bit variable (say low32). In the case where two threads simultaneously try to CAS on high32 and low32 can they both succeed?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.  It would be nice to know if 2 adjacent __int32 interfere?  Would they interfere if not occupying the same cache line?  I assume everything needs to be aligned, but if not, would two adjacent unaligned __int32 interfere.

Comment: @johnnycrash: SO is getting worse by the day. At the bare minimum, we need to force people to leave a comment if they are downvoting something.

Comment: Guess noone has an answer.  You could test this with two threads in an infinite loop, each using CAS on one of the ints.  See if CAS ever fails.

Answer (score 2):

On windows 64 bit, CAS on adjacent ints always succeeds no matter the alignment and no matter if cache lines are crossed (unless my test app has a bug).  I only tested windows 7, 64 bit.

**EDIT:**
This probably is how CAS will work on all modern Intel chips regardless of OS.  I was running on an I7.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

volatile __declspec(align(64)) char a[128];
int _nAlign = 0;

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpThreadParameter)
{
    auto iElem = (int)lpThreadParameter;
    volatile auto* p = (int*)(a + _nAlign + sizeof(int) * iElem);
    for (long long i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
        int nOld = *p, nNew = nOld + 1;
        if (InterlockedCompareExchange((DWORD*)p, (DWORD)nNew, (DWORD)nOld) != nOld)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
        _nAlign = atoi(argv[1]);
    HANDLE aThread[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        aThread[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, (LPVOID)i, 0, NULL);
        SetThreadAffinityMask(aThread[i], 1<<(2*i)); // hyperthreading is on, so make sure on actual separate cores
    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, aThread, true, INFINITE);
    DWORD aCode[2]; 
    if (!GetExitCodeThread(aThread[0], &aCode[0]) || !GetExitCodeThread(aThread[1], &aCode[1]))
        printf("GetExitCodeThread failed\n");
    if (aCode[0] || aCode[1])
        printf("CAS failed\n");
    else
        printf("CAS Succeeded\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed verification. I guessed that both the CAS will succeed. But I will try and record cache statistics to see if this causes cache misses.